# collapse inline form bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, inline

i've added a inline-form to my page, in the main area,

the form is a bit to wide, i would like that it collapse at 991px,

but the rest of the page can collapse at 767px

i understand it can be done with mediaquery but not sure on what to code.

i'm stuck here! 
what can i do?

i copied the inline form originally from a navbar of a file, the button is working fine.

it look like this:

```
<div  class="container">

<div class="text-center">
       <button        
      class="btn btn-default form-toggle" 
      type="button" 
      data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target="#collapseExample" 
      aria-expanded="false" 
      aria-controls="collapseExample"> <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation</span> Reservations 
      </button>
</div>

<div id="collapseExample" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

    <div class="text-center ">

     <form class="form-inline navbar-form" name="bookerform" action="---" method="GET" target="_self">
           <div class="form-group">hidden elements</div>
           <div class="form-group">arrivo</div>
           <div class="form-group">partenza</div>
           <div class="form-group text-left"> Numero N</div>
           <div class="form-group text-left"> Numero A</div>
           <div class="form-group text-left"> Numero B</div>
           <div class="form-group"> button check</div>
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using a `navbar-form`.. Just use the regular bootstrap grid: http://codeply.com/go/fj2PNqXf8F

Comment: thank you, 
yes like this it collapse , 
but i'd like that the form is visible form 992px up, 
and when is lower than 992px the button show up, and the form is not visible, it will be only by clicking on the button...

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your help,
ok actually i'm almost there.
i like the solution using the bootstrap grid, i've added the media queries but it's not showing as i want, from 992 above it should show only the form, not the button

```
<div class="container">
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myForm"> Reservations
    </button>
</div>
<br>
<form class="collapse collapse-class" role="form" id="myForm">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <p>
            <input type="email" class="form-control">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <p>
            <input type="password" class="form-control">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>


@media (max-width: 992px) {
.collapse-class {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do your on custom collapsing with a simple media query and css class. Simply toggle the CSS display from inline-block to block. Here, at 1000px and under, the two selects of the the second td will stack vertically; horizontally above 1000px.

CSS:

```
.collapse-it {
        display: inline-block;
    }

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .collapse-it {
        display:block;
    }

  .mobile-view:after {
    content:"mobile view vertical stacking";
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">

<tbody><tr>
  <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <div style="margin:5px;">credit card expiration</div>
  </td>

<td style="border: 1px solid black;">
<div style="margin:5px;">


  <div class="form-group collapse-it">
    <select>
      <option>a</option>
      <option>b</option>
      <option>c</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group collapse-it">
    <select>
      <option>d</option>
      <option>e</option>
      <option>f</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>                                  
</td>

  <td class="mobile-view" style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>  

</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

[View Demo on Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/J1yZKOKsTP)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to go away at 992px but keep the button, put a class on what you want to collapse, and leave the button outside it. Then write a media query to display: none at 992px like so:

```
<form class="form-inline navbar-form collapse-class" name="bookerform" action="---" method="GET" target="_self">
       <div class="form-group">hidden elements</div>
       <div class="form-group">arrivo</div>
       <div class="form-group">partenza</div>
       <div class="form-group text-left"> Numero N</div>
       <div class="form-group text-left"> Numero A</div>
       <div class="form-group text-left"> Numero B</div>
       <div class="form-group"> button check</div>
  </form>

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .collapse-class {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what you want, so I'm trying to be general.

Comment: Thank you, 
i've tried like you said but i'm unable to make it work  properly
 i've posted the code, with the css....

Comment: @BOBEifel, you need to add that media query with the rest of your CSS. I was showing the two side by side, but the media query needs to be in your CSS style sheet, or wrapped in <style></style> tags, whichever you are using.

Comment: i know that!!
i put it there just to show it,  
in my case is in a external css file